# Wordpress custom plugin shortcode wpdb unknown

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm writing a custom plugin in wordpress and I'm using a shortcode for the first time.
Until now my shortcode works but now I want to execute a query in the function of that shortcode to get all the employees from a specific employee group id

```
   [employee_group_tag group_id=2]
```

This is the file that has my shortcode functionality:

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Employees
Plugin URI: xxx
Description: xxx
Version: 1.0
Author: xxx
Author URI: http://www.blabla.com
*/

   global $wpdb;

   function employee_shortcode_func( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'group_id' => '0',
    ), $atts ) );

    // Alle werknemers ophalen adhv van group_id
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM wp_werknemers_employees WHERE employee_employee_group_id = ' . $group_id;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    return 'test';
}
add_shortcode( 'employee_group_tag', 'employee_shortcode_func' );
```

But when I run this it gets stuck on $wpdb->get_results($sql) because when I leave this out it displays my page correctly but when I want to fill it with employee details I only get the half of my page. So it "breaks"

I tried to do (which works in all my other files)

```
  require_once("../../../wp-config.php")
```

But it doesn't work...

Is it possible that it's not working because its in my "main" plugin file? Because in all my other files I can use wpdb when I use the require function...

any ideas?

Comment: `global wpdb` belongs inside the function.

Comment: Oh my god... never thought of that, you saved my day! :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php):

> For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well. For example:
>
> ```
> $a = 1;
> include 'b.inc';
> ```
>
> Here the `$a` variable will be available within the included `b.inc` script. However, within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope. For example:
>
> ```
> $a = 1; /* global scope */ 
>
> function test()
> { 
>     echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
> } 
>
> test();
> ```

The last example does not work, as `$a` is not defined inside the scope of the function.

Just like in your case, for it to work you have to use:

```
function employee_shortcode_func( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;
    // etc
}
```